# Unable to load data into listview from mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, listview

I am trying to load data from mysql into a listview but not able to do it.I run this piece of code and nothing is displayed on the emulator,after few seconds the app crashes. Please suggest me where I have gone wrong.This is the MainActivity.java file

```
    package com.example.student;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.StrictMode;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView text;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new  StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

       connect();
   }
     private void connect() {
      String data;
       List<String> r = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayAdapter<String>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,r);
     ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
     try {
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://10.10.6.124/android/insert.php");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
        data=EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        Log.e("STRING", data);
        try {

     JSONArray json=new JSONArray(data);
        for(int i=0;i<json.length(); i++)
      {
          JSONObject obj=json.getJSONObject(i);
          String name=obj.getString("name");
          String year=obj.getString("year");
          String age=obj.getString("age");
          Log.e("STRING", name);
          r.add(name);
          r.add(year);
          r.add(age);
          list.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
         }

         } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
               Log.d("HTTPCLIENT", e.getLocalizedMessage());
          } catch (IOException e) {
              Log.d("HTTPCLIENT", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }


         }
      }
```

This is the PHP file index.php

```
    <?php
     header('Content-type: application/json');
     mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","");
     mysql_select_db("student");
     $sql=mysql_query("select * from student");
     while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
     $output[]=$row;
     json_encode($output);
     print(json_encode($output));
     mysql_close();
     ?>
```

Comment: if you are using the emulator then you need to change the ip address to `http://10.0.2.2/android/insert.php` if your server has a port add the port also after the ip like: `10.0.2.2:4444/...`

Comment: what is the result when you call 127.0.0.1 in your web-browser

Comment: when i call 127.0.0.1/student/index.php i get JSON response correctly @Sreekanthss

Comment: what about http://10.10.6.124/android/insert.php in browser ? is this also work?

Comment: no that does'nt work @Sreekanthss

Comment: it means there is some problem with your ip or port, Only you get the response in app if it is accessed from browser . what  is the response you are getting when call url in browser. are you testing the server in the same machine and is that a windows with the tomcat server ?

Comment: Im using wamp server.When I call the url in browser the response what i get is [{"Name":"Sheetal","Year":"1991","Age":"23"},{"Name":"Lakshmi","Year":"1991","Age":"23"},{"Name":"Rahul","Year":"2001","Age":"13"}]

Answer (score 0):

In your connect method you are initializing adapter array with empty String list.

Correct code is:

```
package com.example.student;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.StrictMode;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView text;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new  StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
       connect();
   }
     private void connect() {
      String data;
       List<String> r = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
     ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
     try {
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("yourdomain/android/insert.php");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
        data=EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        Log.e("STRING", data);
        try {
     JSONArray json=new JSONArray(data);
        for(int i=0;i<json.length(); i++)
      {
          JSONObject obj=json.getJSONObject(i);
          String name=obj.getString("name");
          String year=obj.getString("year");
          String age=obj.getString("age");
          Log.e("STRING", name);
          r.add(name);
          r.add(year);
          r.add(age);

            }
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,r);
          list.setAdapter(adapter);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
         }
         } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
               Log.d("HTTPCLIENT", e.getLocalizedMessage());
          } catch (IOException e) {
              Log.d("HTTPCLIENT", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
         }
      }
```

Comment: replace HttpGet request = new HttpGet("yourdomain/android/insert.php"); yourdomain with your domain url, also you were setting list adapter in every iteration of for loop, listview adapter should be set after for loop

Comment: I made the changes as you suggested but still it is not working

Comment: When you print Log.e("STRING", data); , what is printing on log?